# Opengl version trouble glew.h

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2008, glut, glew

I am developing an **OpenG**L application and need to use the **glew** library. I am using **Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express**.

I compiled a program using gl.h, glu.h, and glut.h just fine and it does what it's supposed to do. But after including glew.h it still compiles just fine, but when I try:

```
glewInit();
if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_2_0"))
    printf("Ready for OpenGL 2.0\n");
else {
    printf("OpenGL 2.0 not supported\n");
}
```

It keeps printing:

> "OpenGL 2.0 not supported".

I tried to change it to `glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_1_3")` or even `glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_1_0")` and it still returns false meaning that it does not support OpenGL version whatever.

I have a Radeon HD 5750 so, it should support OpenGL 3.1 and some of the features of 3.2. I know that all the device drivers are installed properly since I was able to run all the programs in the Radeon sdk provided by ATI.

I also installed Opengl Extensions Viewer 3.15 and it says OpenGL Version 3.1 Ati Driver 6.14.10.9116. I tired all of them `GLEW_VERSION_1_1`, `GLEW_VERSION_1_2`, `GLEW_VERSION_1_3`, `GLEW_VERSION_2_0`, `GLEW_VERSION_2_1`, `GLEW_VERSION_3_0` and all of these return false.

Any other suggestioms? I even tried `GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader` `&&` `GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader` and this is returning false as well.

Answer (score 9):

`glewIsSupported` is meant to check and see if the specific features are supported.  You want something more like...

```
if (GLEW_VERSION_1_3)
{
    /* Yay! OpenGL 1.3 is supported! */
}
```

Comment: As the OP said, it does not work, doesn't matter how you use it. This always has its value set to false, I have the same problem here with my OpenGL on linux.

Comment: I believe the OP was passing the string to the glewIsSupported function.  My point was that it is not a string but a global variable in the glew header files.  Which version of GLEW are you using?

Answer (score 2):

there may be some lack of necessary initialization.  I encounter the same question. And here is how I solve the question:  you need to include the `glCreateWindow()` ahead. Include this function and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check whether glew has initialized properly:

```
 if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
 { // something is wrong };
```

Secondly, you need to create the context *before* calling `glewInit()`

Thirdly, you can also try:

```
  glewExperimental=true;
```

Before calling `glewInit()`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when running a program through windows **RDP**, then I noticed that my **video card** may not working properly when using RDP, so I tried **teamviewer** instead, both glewinfo.exe and my program start to work normally then.

The OP's problem may be solved for a long time, just for others' infomation.